# Determining position of pole

Tags: complex-analysis

i would like to know how to determine if pole of given function is inside a circle of radius 2? for example let us take this function
$$
f(z)=1/\cos z
$$
We have poles at 
$$
z=\pm \pi/2, \pm 3\pi/2, \pm 5\pi/2, \dotsc
$$
So which of these poles should be considered for a circle whose radius is 2.

Comment: the ones in the circle: $\pm \pi/2$

Comment: That depends on where the center of the circle is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to compute the modules and see if they are less than $2$.

For exemple $|\pm \frac{\pi}{2}|<2$ since it is well known that $3<\pi<3,5$.

However the other singularities are not in the disk because the module is greater than $2$.

Comment: It means if the contour is unit circle then all the singularities lies outside the circle and I can directly take the integral of the function equal to zero by Cauchy's residue theorem.

Comment: This is correct.